# How to do software performance testing at home

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I want to practice performance testing at home using loadrunner or ibm rational performance tester or jmeter. But for this i need an application on which i can perform testing. Can anyone suggest me such dummy web application on which can do performance testing at home using above tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, LoadRunner comes with [Web Tour Sample Application](http://lrhelp.saas.hp.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/Tutorial/WebTours.htm)

For JMeter or Rational Performance Testing evaluation I would suggest to:

1. Choose any free CMS, E-learning, or E-commerce product i.e.:

   - [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/download)
   - [Moodle](https://download.moodle.org/)
   - [Magento](https://magento.com/products/community-edition)
2. Install it somewhere in your local intranet
3. Get hands-on practice with one of the popular solutions which may be useful in the future.

If possible, install the application you're testing on the separate physical or virtual machine, this way you can learn [how to collect and analyze server-side performance metrics](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) as they matter.

Comment: I think installing above products on local intranet would give real performance bottlenecks as it gives for an application on internet. But still it would be helpful in learning the tool.

Answer (score 2):

Dmitri noted that the commercial tools tend to have available a demo environment used as a part of sales demos and training for just this type of education. These demo apps are great for a controlled environment to teach the mechanical concepts on how to use the tools.  Beyond that, you want something more, ....real....

Download and install at your home any open source application.   SugarCRM is a good one for this type of education.  There are plenty of challenges in the app to keep you busy and it will exercise most capabilities in performance testing tools.

When you feel up to it, there is a challenge you will want to try,

http://www.myloadtest.com/training/correlation-challenge/

This is a single user exercise for ensuring that you get a script working.  Please do not performance test Stuart's website without explicit written permission or this becomes an undesired denial of services action.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use LoadRunner, then by defalut you will get a dummy application provided by HP called  - **WebToursApplication**

Recently I found another dummy banking application by HP called - **ZeroBank**
Please find the link to this application

- http://zero.webappsecurity.com/login.html

Login details are 
Login:**username**
password:**password**

Hope you got what you are looking for.
So Happy Testing.

Answer (score 0):

In looking around, I found:

***Ability to run tests on load generators on Amazon EC2 Cloud**
on 
http://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-Information-and-News/LoadRunner-12-00-Released/td-p/6419972

Here is the Amazon EC2 Cloud Service:
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Currently, I use Codenvy for an IDE.  They don't support the tools you are looking for right now, but I've heard they may offer it in the near future, too.